# MongoDB: Aggregate nested object properties

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am trying to aggregate multiple nested properties using MongoDB aggregation.

Example collection:

```
[{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59c0b704863b6c23edb9671e"),
    "client_id": "c1",
    "errors": {
        "500": 1,
        "404": 3
    }
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("68c0b704863b6c23edb9671e"),
    "client_id": "c1",
    "errors": {
        "404": 1,
        "403": 5,
        "401": 10
    }
}]
```

Desired aggregation query result:

```
{
    "client_id": "c1",
    "errors": {
        "500": 1,
        "404": 4,
        "403": 5,
        "401": 10
    }
}
```

1M records (or more) need to be aggregated this way.

The `errors` keys are not definite or final and can be added on demand, the aggregation should not fail in that case.

I have also considered using arrays with `$unwind` but that is costly.

I can do that quite easily using map-reduce but the dataset is large and performance is not acceptable.

Is there a way to use aggregation efficiently for this kind of task?

Comment: I believe the only solution would be to redesign your scheme to make the errors an actual Key Value Pair, this would make querying the collection a lot easier.

Comment: @Skami do you mean like this?
`[{code: '404', value: '4'}, ...]`

Comment: Correct but keep in mind that the value needs to be an `int` like this `[{
   "code": "418",
   "value": 3
  }, ... ]` otherwise you'll have issues "summing" them.

Comment: @Skami yes the quotes on value was a typo. I've tried that but `$unwind` is pretty expensive, I can't get it to perform well. I'm trying to flatten the records and see if it makes a difference.